# MIPS function that converts integer to binary/decimal?

Tags: assembly, binary, decimal, converters, mips

I'm writing a MIPS assembly program and I'm trying to figure out a way to display a given integer in either decimal or binary using only one function with two parameters. The function takes in two parameters: an integer and a base (either '2' or '10'). I'd like to not edit anything other than just this one function.

Can anyone help me create such a function? I can't wrap my head around the logic needed to do so using assembly language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try writing an algorithm in C first. That should give you a hint as to what the structure of your MIPS program should look like.

Comment: I've already tried using a recursive algorithm but I'm unsure how to implement it in MIPS. Allocating/deallocating space on the stack for parameter passing gets confusing during recursion.

Comment: In which case, add your algorithm written in C to the question. It will help people give you better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched online and found solution [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/72982/converting-decimal-value-to-binary-mips).
It worked in my code, I'll suggest do try it.

The whole credit goes to [RubyBEW](https://www.daniweb.com/members/282148/rustybew), who wrote and published the code.

Let me know if this helps